# How to create a PHP Script that creates OpenVPN Files (And answers to bash file)

Tags: php, shell, openvpn

I´m setting up a PHP Script to create OpenVPN files for clients.

The PHP Script needs to be able to do the following: 
- Change the directory and execute different files (done)
- Download the OpenVPN files right after (done)

Execute a bash script called "build-key.sh" 
The Problem: The bash script is asking questions. A question like What country, What City (..) the user has to type in his information. This questions shall be answered through PHP Variables as this will always stay the same.

How do I tell my PHP script to answer to this question with the given PHP Variables?

Comment: Question responses are given via the standard input. The first example in [`proc_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) describes how you can pass data through the standard input

Comment: Hello! 

Thanks for your fast reply.

Can you give me an code example of answering to the question: 

" Do you really want to create this certificate? Enter y or n"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Based on the PHP manual example you'd do `fwrite($pipes[0], 'y'.PHP_EOL);` that should transmit a `y` followed by a newline (which is what a user would do). There's no actual need to wait for the output to display the message, the input will not be consumed until the process explicitly calls a read command on the input stream

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I´ll try that out.

Comment: @apokryfos Hello! 

Its almost working. 

Now i get the following message in the error.log created bei proc_open: 

sh: 1: /root/openvpn-ca/build-key.sh: Permission denied
sh: 1: /root/openvpn-ca/build-key.sh: Permission denied

I already gave the build-key.sh 777 permissions, the PHP script has the same permissions (as long as i test) 

Is there anything i am missing when it comes to file permissions? 

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well the script may have 777 permissions but the directory it is going to write to belongs to root and when your run a script via PHP you are running it as the user who executes PHP.  I would advise against using the `/root/...` directory when doing this and instead make a dedicated path just for PHP to work in with all the permissions on the file and the directory.

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer.

I now have the following problem: the error.log shows: 
/openvpn-ca/build-key.sh: not found 

But the path is right.